# By Kuratowski's theorem this graph seems to be planar so why is it 5 colourable considering the Four Colour theorem?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

```
    o
    |
 o--o--o 
    |
    o
```

(the dashed lines represent arcs and o represents nodes)

I can't see any way this graph contains a subgraph homeomorphic to K5 or K3,3 so by Kuratowski's theorem this suggests the graph is planar.

Four Colour theorem says that the vertices of every planar graph can be coloured with at most four colours so that no two adjacent vertices receive the same colour.

So why is the graph above 5-colourable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not by any means an expert in graph theory (in fact, I have little to no knowledge on the subject), but still I'll point out that you can indeed color this graph with only two colours. That's because no arc connects to any of the sorrounding ones except for the middle one, so your "leaf" vertices do not "touch" if you were to draw a map resembling this diagram.

You could also have all the vertices as drawn areas touching each others, making this diagram:

```
   o
 / | \
o--o--o
 \ | /
   o
```

and you could still colour this one with only three colours: two vertices opposing the  centre one don't actually connect.

For example, you could have green for the middle one, yellow for the top and the bottom ones, and blue for the left and right ones.

Anyway, keep in mind that the Four Colour Theorem says that you **can** colour it with at most four colors - if you were to be extremely conservative about the number of colours to use. But in facts, you may as well colour the map with as many colours as the number of vertices in your graph.

Comment: Thanks! Just realised how obvious that is